# "Not connected to Docker" in Intellij even though "Connection successful"

Tags: docker, intellij-idea

I am new to using Docker with Intellij and am using default auto-generated settings.  For a new Docker Run configuration we can see the Dockerfile was selected - and crucially the default MacOS Docker Server was selected:

[image]

The connection is successful:

[image]

However when I attempt to run this configuration an error message and/or dialog box saying "Not connected to docker"

[image]

Am i missing a step? What needs to be done to be able to run/debug this Docker image?

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the logs attached via Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data.

Comment: @CrazyCoder https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-277307?clearDraft=true&description=%0A%0AIU-212.4746.92,%20JRE%2011.0.11%2B9-b1504.13x64%20JetBrains%20s.r.o.,%20OS%20Mac%20OS%20X(x86_64)%20v11.5.1,%20screens%203840.0x2400.0;%20Retina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lead QA at JetBrains @CrazyCoder (and highly prolific Answerer here on SOF) requested a bug submission for this : it is at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-277307.

**Update**: the *very very* latest version of IJ **20.2.1** has this completely ***fixed*** !  The two-weeks ago version was mine at  20.2 (new laptop install) so that minor release did the job!

[image]